# How would a nightclub in a post-apocalyptic future look like?

Tags: post-apocalypse, cyberpunk

I am studying theatre directing. It’s a thing of beauty to build a world for a set design.

So: I’ve written a text that will be played by actors. It’s about a computer programmer who meets and falls in love with a weirdo, she’s called the Great Bum, a sort of an android, a cyber-girl that teases him with surrealist music that she plays. She’s a Singer in the nightclub where they meet.

The world is trying to cope with the apocalypse (cosmic objects are approaching Earth, and the atmosphere is very dark and poisonous, but also very aphrodisiac - people feel the urge to have sex in such a dangerous space-time)

The nightclub is very much like a bunker - it’s safe for the party animals. But how do you think it would look like (in a detailed version)?

Thank you,
Monica

Comment: Are you looking for realism or aesthetics? If it is the latter you can go with whatever you need to create the desired atmosphere. If you need a more realistic answer it would be nice to have more details about your world, technology, size, features and location of this club. Clubs in the US, Asia, and Europe are somewhat different. The wealth of the guests also makes a difference. Cheap clubs are not decorated the same way as expensive clubs. You also need to decide whether you want to go with the genre conventions.

Comment: I am already interested in a girl who goes by "Great Bum".

Comment: Hi Monica. I try not to VTC newcomers, but this question is the poster child for "opinion based." It's impossible to answer "what would a night club look like in Atlanta, GA today?" without being opinion-based. Should it have lights or not? lasers or not? dancing girls or not? neon or not? one bar or two? Should its theme be western? disco? 50's retro (hello Fallout!)? techno punk? cyberpunk? Should it serve straight alcohol or mixed drinks? Should it cut the drinks with formaldehyde like many speakeasys did during Prohibition? (\*continued\*)

Comment: Please remember that on this site, worldbuilding (on-topic) is about the development and consistent use of rules and systems that define a fictional world of your own creation wherein an infinite number of stories can be told. Storybuilding (off-topic) is about circumstances, plot, and character actions/choices. In other words, "what would my nightclub look like?" is off-topic because it's 100% circumstantial. On the other hand... (\*continued\*)

Comment: ...a Q like "Given the following very detailed list of environmental, political, and demographic conditions, how could my post-apocalyptic nightclub get alcohol?" would be on-topic because it's asking about a system that doesn't depend on window dressing.

Comment: I note this is in fact pre-apocalytic.

Comment: Quite apart from everything else, you should remember that if you actually want people to stage this piece, it needs to be - well - stageable! It's all well and good to call for, say, a massive cave in the style of *The Matrix*, but can you get it built?

Comment: Given the massive amount of variation of nightclubs within even one city on present day Earth, let alone across the globe what makes you think that there would be 1 definitive answer to what a nightclub would look like after an apocalypse?

Comment: Are you writing in British or American English?  Because "Great Bum" means very different things in the two.  About the same difference as "knock up" :-)

Comment: @jamesqf I can't speak for my British cousins, but "Great Bum" has both connotations where I live, and if said in the company of 100 random people, 50 of them would be chuckling for one reason and 50 for the other... but they'd all be chuckling. I'm in favor of flat out believing that was the OP's intention: a pun that would make the audience world-over laugh and groan at the same time.

Answer (score 5):

I feel like nightclubs are one of the most-portrayed, if not THE most-portrayed, cyberpunk settings.

You can find lists of examples at https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CyberPunkIsTechno and https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CoolestClubEver

In Second Life, pretty much everyone builds a cyberpunk nightclub, it's the most common location type.

Image search for 'cyberpunk nightclub': https://yandex.com/images/search?text=cyberpunk%20nightclub

Breakdown of the visual elements of cyberpunk interiors: https://old.reddit.com/r/Cyberpunk/wiki/decor

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yup.  Definitely lots of examples to choose.  I was going to suggest the [NeedWant in Defiance](https://defiance.fandom.com/wiki/NeedWant)

Answer (score 5):

From the inside it would probably just look like a regular nightclub.   In times of stress of stress people like to be reminded of the good old days.  So From the outside The place might be a reinforced concrete bunker with with armed guards patrolling,  But from the inside it probably looked very similar if not identical to what we would see at 21 St. Century night club, Just with a little bit more technology And a little bit more cybernetic customers.

As the other answer said you can con find examples of night clubs like this all over sience fiction.

Comment: But what does a "regular" nightclub look like?  There are were many variations in my nightclubbing days, and I assume that remains true today, and will in your pre-apocalyptic future.  They've certainly changed over the years: compare say descriptions of 1920s speakeasies with clubs today.

Comment: @jamesqf yes but those are things I can't predict so not apart of what should  be  included in an answer on world builders as a put in my answer there would be technology changes but which depends on the creator so I didn't get into it.

Answer (score 4):

**It would look like a bunker.**

[image: bunker]

https://www.theguardian.com/books/2020/aug/11/bunker-building-for-the-end-times-by-bradley-garrett-review-the-new-doom-boom

Because that is what it is.  This one is being used as a night club.  There are light effects along the walls.  The acoustics are less than idea for reproducing recorded music.  But for live music, the artists factor in the acoustic properties of this venue and it is awesome.

Comment: "I feel like nightclubs are one of the most-portrayed, if not THE most-portrayed, cyberpunk settings."  Which maybe says something about those who write and/or consume cyberpunk.  But in the real world, how many people actually spend much time in nightclubs?

Comment: @jamesqf - I envision the virtual nightclub from Snow Crash.  There are people who spend a _lot_ of time in virtual environments.

Comment: Not that many, I'd guess, as a fraction of the population.  Though I see that I put the comment on the wrong answer.  It was meant to go on the one (currently) above, that has half a dozen pictures.  I paged right past the break :-(

Answer (score 2):

The flash of another impact.. large holes in the ceiling allow dust and smoke pouring in

Below, young people dance and party, to the end of times..

[image]

KHAOS festival in Tessaloniki 2012.